# Infinite redirect loop after facebook authenication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, user-controls

I am trying to use facebook authentication on my asp.net application.

I am using Facebook JavaScript SDK calls for this purpose.

In my case, I call the facebook javascript SDK from my normal Default.aspx page, then it authenticates, then sends the uid and access token to a data handler I created. In the datahandler I am creating the session. Then I redirect to the parent page from the data handler.

All this works fine when I am using a normal ASPX page (not any usercontrol). But when I use the same logic inside any user control and call the user control from the default.aspx page (in this case the facebook authentication and facebook login button is inside my user control), after authentication and calling data handler, when I redirect to my default.aspx from my datahandler, this cycle goes on infinitely.

My page keeps on authenticating and keeps on calling the datahandler when then again calls the default.aspx

Please suggest any good approach where I can authenticate the user and come back to my default.aspc when it has the user control.

I created my facebook authentication logic (used only the javascript and datahandler logic) by following this tutorial: 
http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started

I can attach the code also if requested.

Comment: No, it always looped. I am not looking for approach given in this link: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/